# Debugging an exception with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I've got an exception (NullReference, specifically) thrown by my code in WPF. The trouble is, since WPF uses reflection internally, I've lost every single useful  piece of debug information. I don't even have the line or file where the exception was thrown. How can I debug this? I already tried wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch, but that didn't catch the exception for some reason.

What can I do about this?

Comment: You can set VS to break when specific exceptions are thrown so you set that up and wait for it to occur.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in the "Exceptions" dialog to "Thrown"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio, Debug->Exceptions->Find->NullReference and check Thrown. Now if you Debug the project in VS, VS should break on the exception.